# Facing issue with google-dataflow job using BigQueryIO.Read.from(projectId+":"+tableName)

Tags: google-bigquery

I am facing an issue with google dataflow job to read from BigQuery table.

Tried couple of options to read from BigQuery but in both cases are not successful.

First run triggered after deploying the template to GCP is successful i.e., data fetched from BQ table as per expectations.

Same job when triggered 2nd time and all next runs are not fetching the data but instead job is completing successfully if I go with Option A.

Whereas if I try with OptionB i.e., using fromQuery I am getting the error (mentioned below) from 2nd run onwards.

(Note that in both options my first run is always successful after deploying the template to GCP)

Sample code: (OPTION A)

```
p.apply("ReadXXXXTable",BigQueryIO.Read.from(projectId+":"+tableName))
```

I tried other option (OPTION B) i.e., to use fromQuery:

```
p.apply(BigQueryIO.Read
    .named("ReadXXXXX")
    .fromQuery("SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM [" + projectId +  ":" + tableName + "] where fieldx='XXX' and datediff(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),TIMESTAMP(field3))=0 order by field3 desc"))
```

In case of OPTION B I am getting the following error:

> java.io.IOException error, caused by com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException

Comment: Are you including the dataset too? `<project>:<dataset>.<table_name>`

Comment: Yes dataset is included.

Comment: So, `tableName` has dataset in included?

Comment: Yes That's correct.